# Django html set up

Tags: html, django, web

I have a basic website set up with Django and have been following the sentdex tutorials. I cannot figure out how to include the blog posts (I'm assuming this would be either blog.html or post.html) in the bootstrap 'about' section, which I Have renamed blog. Basically, I want the blog posts (derived from the database) to appear here in the 'about' section in bootstrap, rather than at the bottom or in a separate page.

I have an 'aboutme' app (main website) that contains the **home.html**

```
{%extends "aboutme/header.html" %}

{%block content%}
<p>Welcome to this "about" page that is all about the website: 

{%include "aboutme/includes/mysnippet.html"%}
{% endblock %}


{%block blogcontent%}
{% endblock %}
```

..and a **header.html** which contains the whole index.html of the bootstrap site itself. Below is the about section of the **bootstrap websit about/blog section** that includes the django templating logic (block content)

```
<!-- About Section (Blog)-->
<section class="bg-primary text-white mb-0" id="about">
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="text-center text-uppercase text-white">Blog</h2>
    <hr class="star-light mb-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4 ml-auto">
        <p class="lead">This is the blog section</p>
        {%block blogcontent%}
        {%endblock %}

      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 mr-auto">
        <p class="lead">The blogs outlined in the models section and stored in the database, are going to be displayed here.</p>

      </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="text-center mt-4">
      <a class="btn btn-xl btn-outline-light" href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-download mr-2"></i>
        Download Now!
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Finally, I have another app called 'blog', and inside the templates/blog directory for that app:
post.html and blog.html

**blog.html**

```
 {% extends "aboutme/header.html" %}

{%block content %}
    {% for post in object_list %}
        <h5>{{post.date|date:"Y-m-d"}}<a href="/blog/{{post.id}}">{{post.title}}</a></h5>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

**post.html**

```
{% extends "aboutme/header.html" %}

{%block content %}
    <h3>{{post.title}}</h3>
    <h6>on{{post.date}}</h6>
    {{post.body|safe|linebreaks}}
{% endblock %}
```

at the moment when I type http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog  ...the blog posts appear at the bottom of the page, or wherever I place the  {%block content %}{% endblock %} (but it only seems to work at the bottom of the page).

How do I get the blog posts to appear in the 'about me' section of the bootstrap website?

I'd also love an explanation on what exactly the home.html page does and can it be named anything or does it have to be 'home'. Is there where everything is defined in terms of what is displayed, and how does it work?

Comment: Which template is being considered as the base ?
That tempalte : {% extends "aboutme/header.html"  %} ?

because I don't see where you put {% block content %}{% endblock %} inside it

Comment: the aboutme app and the header.html is being considered as the index or base ..

Comment: Basically, I want to know how I got put post.html or blog.html (so draw on the database values stored for the posts) and put them in the header.html dynamically. At the moment I have to go to 127.0.0.1:8000/blog to get the blog posts to show up in the main website, and can't see how to get them to show up in the main......

Comment: rather than use extends in the post/blog html pages, 
just use include in your index.html template : ({% include 'path/post.html' %} or {% include 'path/blog.html' %}) and inside it, don't use block. Make sure you call all the post/blog contexts in the root url through index

Comment: The templates can be named whatever you like. Saying "I type http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog" doesn't tell what view and what urls you are using. You may want to consider reading the docs about how to couple url with views and templates, and post the code as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Edit/Design your codes like that:

Html stuff for index or aboutme/header.html

```
// codes here 

{% block blogcontent %}
    {% include 'path/blog.html' %}
{% enblock %}

// codes here 

{% block postcontent %}
    {% include 'path/post.html' %}
{% enblock %}


<!-- end  -->
```

when you call 127.0.0.1:8000, everything will be available there.
and for other links, if you don't want to display the blog or post block,
just use {% block blogcontent %}{% endblock %} {% block postcontent %}{% endblock %} whitout anything inside

Comment: I know how to do this....but what I DON'T know how to do is get the posts to display ....post.html draws on the database and is part of another app. On moving it in here, or even if I leave it in the app it is in, the posts don't seem to display inside of this bootstrap page, unless I type in 127.0.0.1:8000/blog

Comment: In your view, you should query the post table, and send it to the template through context

Comment: I have used: {%include "blog/post.html"%}  and am trying to get to the html file in the following path: C:\Users\User\Desktop\Django Tutorials\understanding_html_setup\pythonsite\mysite\blog\templates\blog ///but it doesn't work. I've also tried {%include "blog/blog/post.html"%}  and {%include "blog/templates/blog/post.html"%} but nothing works!

Comment: Wow ! many things need to be solved, but first off: tell me or localize your post.html in your project, this is really important, what do you set to settings.TEMPLATES_DIRS ? never use the full path in your projects, let django and python do this.